# Is it bad practice to define functions in main.cpp rather than in header files?

Tags: c++, function, prototype

Is it bad practice to define functions in the file containing the main function rather than header files and their corresponding .cpp file? What I currently do is declare my function prototypes at the beginning of the file before the main function and then define the functions at the end after the end of my main function. Would an employer consider this to be noobish?

Comment: As long as main.cpp does not grow 2000+lines, this is quite ok, to me.

Comment: It's not bad practice, but I find it more convenient to avoid forward declarations if possible and just have `main` be the last function. But that's just a personal taste. It's not "noobish" to do it one way or the other.

Comment: @bipll: I'd say 2000 is fine, though I'd be slightly concerned when it reaches [300000](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36413769).

Comment: thanks for the fast responses!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good practice to keep everything as local as possible. If the functions are not accessed outside the .cpp file, don't put them in the header file (you may want to put local helper functions in an anonymous namespace, though).

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you're doing, for instance if you're working on a project that's going to make use of classes you may want to move them into a separate header file and or .cpp especially if you plan on reusing the functions and classes you've made.

If the project is small than you really don't have to worry about it and it's neither correct nor incorrect at that point (and in general) you should try to be as efficient as possible and each situation is different so you have to look at each one when you come to it :)